# Google application script <?= var ?>

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to print a variable from the .gs code within an HTML document using

```
<?= var ?>
```

I know I have done this before, but when I do it now, the entire tag is just rendered - so the page displays

```
<?= var ?>
```

rather than do anything with GAS.

Comment: How are you rendering it?

Comment: OK.  It is a problem with using

return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('

vs.

return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('

However.  I can not set a viewport with .createTemplateFromFile.  This is critical as it is mobile only.

Comment: OK.  I think I was just not getting it right.  You CAN use the meta tag with the .createTemplateFromFile.  This is working (as best as I can tell)

return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('LoginPage.html').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');

Answer (score 1):

Yea, that checks out.  You CAN use the .createTemplateFromFile with viewport, and must use .createTemplateFromFile not .createTemplateFromFile with any scripting.

Simple enough, just don't use it often enough to keep it all straight.